# Kotlin JSON Data not arranging into arraylist properly with Retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I'm working on a kotlin android app with Retrofit. I'm making an API call to IEX stock data using this link:
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb,ge&types=quote

The JSON data doesn't seem to arrange itself into an arraylist naturally.  When I plug the data into jsonschema2pojo, it tells me that I should create class names for each of the stocks like this:

```
public class GE {
@SerializedName("quote")
@Expose
public Quote__ quote;
}
```

Naturally, I want the stock names to be variable so I can plug any list into there.  Is there something wrong with the JSON data, or am I missing a step??

My Methods in case you wanted to see them (They're generic):

```
private fun getStock(stock: String) {
    Timber.d("Start Retrofit Get Stocks")
    val service = initiateRetrofit()
    val call = service.queryStock("GE")
    Timber.d("Url: " + call.request().url())
    call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<StockModel> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<StockModel>, response: retrofit2.Response<StockModel>) {
            Timber.d("Successful Query. Message: " + response.message())
            val stocklist : StockModel = response.body()
            Timber.d("See what you get in the stock model")
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<StockModel>, t: Throwable) {
            Timber.d("Failed Call: " + t)
        }
    })
}

private fun initiateRetrofit(): RetrofitService {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(RetrofitService.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build()
    return retrofit.create(RetrofitService::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Can you post all your Bean class because retrofit is dependent on bean hierarchy?

Comment: i provide code and test it. it is working. if you have any error then tell me. and if working then pl accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a really clean and simple way of solving for this problem.

To get at the `"quote"` JSON object, you'll want to create a custom JSON deserializer. The `JsonDeserializer` is an interface that you implement from the Gson library.

First, we need our response object to use for deserialization.

```
// PortfolioResponse.kt
class PortfolioResponse {
    var quotes: List<Quote>? = null
}
```

Next, we'll setup our `ApiService` class to make a call for a `PortfolioResponse` object.

```
// ApiService.kt
interface ApiService {
    @GET("stock/market/batch")
    abstract fun queryStockList(@Query("symbols") stocks: String, @Query("types") types: String): Call<PortfolioResponse>
}
```

Then, setup the deserializer. This is where we'll strip the unnecessary JSON object keys, and get the `"quote"` JSON objects we're looking for.

```
// PortfolioDeserializer.kt
class PortfolioDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<PortfolioResponse> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): PortfolioResponse {
        val portfolioResponse = PortfolioResponse()

        json?.let {
            val jsonObject = it.asJsonObject
            val symbolSet = jsonObject.entrySet()
            val quoteElements = ArrayList<JsonObject>()
            val quotes = ArrayList<Quote>()
            val gson = Gson()

            // this will give us a list of JSON elements that look like ""Quote": {}"
            symbolSet.mapTo(quoteElements) { it.value.asJsonObject }

            // this will take each quote JSON element, and only grab the JSON that resembles a Quote
            // object, and add it to our list of Quotes
            quoteElements.mapTo(quotes) { gson.fromJson(it.entrySet().first().value, Quote::class.java) }

            portfolioResponse.quotes = quotes
        }

        return portfolioResponse
    }
}
```

Finally, update your existing network call in your Activity, and it's done.

```
// MainActivity.kt
call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<PortfolioResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<PortfolioResponse>, response: retrofit2.Response<PortfolioResponse>) {
                Timber.d("Successful Market Batch Query. Response.body=${response.body()}")
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<PortfolioResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Timber.d("Failed Call: " + t)
            }
        })
```

Comment: With this method, I was able to get an array list of stock quotes for any queried list of stocks. Thanks!!

Comment: My issue is resolved using your answer Thanks!!! ....... Question: https://github.com/ResoCoder/forecast-mvvm-android-kotlin/issues/12

Answer (score 1):

The data is in a `Map`, not an array. Looks like the automated converter is trying to make it an object with field names.  Try making your return value in your retrofit interface `Call<Map<String, Quote__>>`.

You will need to update the rest of your code to pull the key and values out of the map for processing.